# Jquery live search: fire with button?

Tags: jquery, livesearch

I found [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/alecrust/pcfLJ/) that functions exactly how I want it to on my page, except I need for the search to occur only when the user clicks a search button (which I could also use help adding) or hits the enter key - NOT while they are typing.

Here's the code:

```
//Live Search
$('.filter-bar #search').search('.filter-results li', function(on) {
on.all(function(results) {
    var size = results ? results.size() : 0
    $('.filter-results-count').text(size + ' results');
});

on.reset(function() {
    $('.no-filter-results').hide();
    $('.filter-results li').show();
});

on.empty(function() {
    $('.no-filter-results').show();
    $('.filter-results li').hide();
});

on.results(function(results) {
    $('.no-filter-results').hide();
    $('.filter-results li').hide();
    results.show();
 });
});
```

The next step would be making the search not case sensitive and account for some type-o's.
(Could I use quick silver or liquid metal or something like that?)

If you could modify the fiddle to solve that would be best for me to understand.

Comment: You will eventually have to learn JS properly, why not go through some tutorials now?

Comment: @Asad The answer to that question is usually "Deadlines."

Comment: @Blazemonger Right, but you can meet deadlines much more quickly if you learn how to do the task without external input. Just modifying the piece of code is one way to answer the question, but I don't think this approach to solving problems will be sustainable for the OP in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

There is a library added which makes the search possible. I've edited the original code. Please use the code below! This will only search when you press the enter key. But the rest is still the same.

```
(function($) {
  var Search = function(block) {
    this.callbacks = {};
    block(this);
  }

  Search.prototype.all = function(fn) { this.callbacks.all = fn; }
  Search.prototype.reset = function(fn) { this.callbacks.reset = fn; }
  Search.prototype.empty = function(fn) { this.callbacks.empty = fn; }
  Search.prototype.results = function(fn) { this.callbacks.results = fn; }

  function query(selector) {
    if (val = this.val()) {
      return $(selector + ':contains("' + val + '")');;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  $.fn.search = function search(selector, block) {
    var search = new Search(block);
    var callbacks = search.callbacks;

    function perform() {
      if (result = query.call($(this), selector)) {
        callbacks.all && callbacks.all.call(this, result);
        var method = result.size() > 0 ? 'results' : 'empty';
        return callbacks[method] && callbacks[method].call(this, result);
      } else {
        callbacks.all && callbacks.all.call(this, $(selector));
        return callbacks.reset && callbacks.reset.call(this);
      };
    }

    $(this).live('keypress', function(e){
        if( e.which == 13) perform();
    });
  }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: thank you, I used you code and my page returned this error citing jquery as the source: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toLowerCase' of undefined" thanks again